# Can I solve the UNABLE TO LOCK ROW error with FOR UPDATE in this spot?

Tags: upsert, dmlexception, apex-webservice

First of all, i've read most other posts about this error. The problem i have here is the code that was written in my org is using an UPSERT so don't see the spot where i can use the FOR UPDATE to avoid this.
Error:

> Exception: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record: []
>   Stack Trace: Class.TransactionWS.insertTransaction: line 165, column 1

Line 165 :

```
upsert listTransactionInsert Reference__c;
```

This call is done in a WS @httpPost function which i copy here:

```
@HttpPost
global static UtilsWS.JSONResponseList insertTransaction(){    
    String error;
    Boolean res;
    String message;
    UtilsWS.ProcessedData processedData = new UtilsWS.ProcessedData();

    try{
        // Check if the WS is enabled
        UtilsWS.checkWSEnabled('TransactionWS');

        // Get request data and deserialize Json
        String bodyString   = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
        List<JsonTransaction> listReq = (List<JsonTransaction>) JSON.deserialize(bodyString, List<JsonTransaction>.class); 

        // Check record amount limits 
        if(listReq.size() > 500){
            throw new UtilsWS.wsException('The max amount of records is 500');
        } 
        if(listReq.size() < 1){
            throw new UtilsWS.wsException('There is not records to insert');
        }               

        // Get and map the RecordTypeIds for all transactions
        for(RecordType rt : [SELECT id, developerName FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType = 'Transaction__c']){
            if(rt.developerName == 'Order'){
                TransactionWS.mapTypeRecordTypeId.put('Order', rt.Id);
            }else if(rt.developerName == 'Trading'){
                TransactionWS.mapTypeRecordTypeId.put('Trade', rt.Id);
            }else if(rt.developerName == 'Invoicing'){
                TransactionWS.mapTypeRecordTypeId.put('Invoice', rt.Id);
            }else if(rt.developerName == 'Clearing'){
                TransactionWS.mapTypeRecordTypeId.put('Clearing', rt.Id);
            }  
        }

        Map<String,JsonTransaction> mapTransactionProvidersBeneficiary = new Map<String, JsonTransaction>();
        Map<String,JsonTransaction> transactionProvidersBeneficiary = new Map<String, JsonTransaction>();
        List<String> listClients = new List<String>();

        Set<String> companies = new Set<String>(),
                    names = new Set<String>(),
                    salespersons = new Set<String>();

        for(JsonTransaction a: listReq){
            listClients.add(a.company_id);
            salespersons.add(a.salesperson_reference);
            if (a.record_type == 'Trade'){
                listClients.add(a.counter_company_uid);
                if (a.beneficiary_type == 'provider'){
                    // We will use the the email to map their transactions. It email field is empty we will use a composed company+lastName as key
                    if(!String.isBlank(a.email)){
                        mapTransactionProvidersBeneficiary.put(a.email.toLowerCase().trim(), a);
                    }else{
                        if(!transactionProvidersBeneficiary.containsKey(TransactionWS.generateKey(a))){
                            transactionProvidersBeneficiary.put(TransactionWS.generateKey(a),a);
                        } 
                        if(!companies.contains(a.beneficiary_name)){
                            companies.add(a.beneficiary_name);
                        }  
                        if(!names.contains(a.provider_contact_name)){
                            names.add(a.provider_contact_name);
                        } 
                    }
                } 
            }               
        }

        // We map the myorg User Id with the SFDC Id for all Users involved
        UtilsWS.getUsersMap(salespersons); 

        // Mapping of myorg Account Id with the Account Ids.
        for (Account a : [SELECT Id, myorg_Account_ID__c, Name FROM Account WHERE myorg_Account_ID__c IN :listClients]){
            TransactionWS.mapCompanyAccountId.put(a.myorg_Account_ID__c, a);
        }

        // If there isn't any account in our DB with these myorg Account Id
        if(mapCompanyAccountId.size()<= 0){
            throw new UtilsWS.wsException('The clients should exists on Salesforce. Client list: '+listClients);
        }        

        List<Transaction__c> listTransactionInsert = new List<Transaction__c>();
        for(JsonTransaction a: listReq){
            listTransactionInsert.add(a.setSFTransaction(new Transaction__c()));
        }

        /** Process to create leads from providers begins**/
        List<Lead> listLeadInsert = new List<Lead>();
        List<Task> listTaskInsertNewLeads = new List<Task>();

        // If already exists an account with the provider's email we remove it from the list.
        for (Account a : [SELECT Id, Company_Email__c FROM Account WHERE Company_Email__c in :mapTransactionProvidersBeneficiary.keySet()]){
            JsonTransaction jt = mapTransactionProvidersBeneficiary.remove(a.Company_Email__c);
        }

        // If already exists a contact with that email it's removed too. 
        for(Contact c : [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email in :mapTransactionProvidersBeneficiary.keySet()]){
            mapTransactionProvidersBeneficiary.remove(c.Email);
        }

        // If already exists a lead with that email or from that company, we create a new task for the existing email.
        for (Lead l : [SELECT Id, LastName, Company, Email FROM Lead WHERE Email in :mapTransactionProvidersBeneficiary.keySet() OR (LastName in :names AND Company in :companies)]){
            if( !String.isBlank(l.Email) && mapTransactionProvidersBeneficiary.containsKey(l.Email)){
                JsonTransaction jt = mapTransactionProvidersBeneficiary.remove(l.Email);
            }else if(transactionProvidersBeneficiary.containsKey(generateKey(l))){
                transactionProvidersBeneficiary.remove(generateKey(l));
            }
        }

        // If we didn't find any Lead, Contact or Account, we create a new Lead.
        for (JsonTransaction jt : mapTransactionProvidersBeneficiary.values()){
            Lead l = new Lead(
                    lastName = jt.provider_contact_name,
                    Email = jt.email,
                    Company = jt.beneficiary_name,
                    CountryCode = jt.beneficiary_country,
                    Bank_Name__c = jt.beneficiary_bank,
                    Bank_Iban__c = jt.beneficiary_iban,
                    Type__c = jt.beneficiary_type,
                    Description = 'Currency Received: '+jt.buy_currency,
                    OwnerId= UtilsWS.getUserId(jt.salesperson_reference),
                    Source_Spec__c = SOURCE_SPEC,    
                    LeadSource = PROVIDERS_SOURCE);
            if(TransactionWS.mapCompanyAccountId.containsKey(jt.company_id)){
                l.Description = 'This Lead is a provider of ' + TransactionWS.mapCompanyAccountId.get(jt.company_id).Name + '\n' +l.Description;
            } 
            listLeadInsert.add(l);
        }

        for(JsonTransaction jt : transactionProvidersBeneficiary.values()){
                    Lead l = new Lead(
                    lastName = jt.provider_contact_name,
                    Company = jt.beneficiary_name,
                    CountryCode = jt.beneficiary_country,
                    Bank_Name__c = jt.beneficiary_bank,
                    Bank_Iban__c = jt.beneficiary_iban,
                    Description = 'Currency Received: '+jt.buy_currency,
                    Type__c = jt.beneficiary_type,
                    OwnerId= UtilsWS.getUserId(jt.salesperson_reference),
                    Source_Spec__c = SOURCE_SPEC,    
                    LeadSource = PROVIDERS_SOURCE);
            if(TransactionWS.mapCompanyAccountId.containsKey(jt.company_id)){
                l.Description = 'This Lead is a provider of ' + TransactionWS.mapCompanyAccountId.get(jt.company_id).Name + '\n' +l.Description;
            } 
            listLeadInsert.add(l);
        }
        if (listTransactionInsert.size()>0){
            upsert listTransactionInsert Reference__c;             
        }  
        if(listLeadInsert.size()>0){
            insert listLeadInsert;
            // We create a task for Sales to check the new leads created. We can disable it using the custom settings.
            if( ControlEnabled__c.getValues('ProviderTasks')!=null && ControlEnabled__c.getValues('ProviderTasks').Enabled__c){
                String taskSubject = label.ProvidersSubject;
                String taskDescription = 'Hello\nA new provider has been created as Lead as it is beneficiary of a Trade. Please contact with them for follow up\nRegards\nmyorg';              
                for (Lead l : listLeadInsert){
                    JsonTransaction jt = mapTransactionProvidersBeneficiary.remove(l.Email);
                    Task t = new Task (Subject = taskSubject, 
                                       Description = taskDescription, 
                                       WhoId = l.Id, 
                                       Type  = 'Record Assignment', 
                                       OwnerId = l.OwnerId);
                    listTaskInsertNewLeads.add(t);
                }               
            }
        }
        if (listTaskInsertNewLeads.size()>0){
            insert listTaskInsertNewLeads;
        } 
        if(processedData.errors.size()>0){
            UtilsWS.generateRESTErrorLog(bodyString, FOLDER_ID,processedData.errors);
            message = 'KO';
        }
        else{
            message ='OK';
        }    
        res = true;
    } 
    catch(Exception e){
        res = false;
        message = e.getMessage();
        processedData = null; 
        Util.sendExceptionEmail('TransactionWS Exception',e);
        UtilsWS.generateRESTExceptionLog(RestContext.request.requestBody.toString(), FOLDER_ID, e);         
    }
    return new UtilsWS.JSONResponseList(res,message,processedData );
 }
```

I actually don't see how to avoid getting the UNABLE TO BLOCK ROW error, i get it once in a while but we could lose some important transactions on the way.

Maybe it's a silly question, but i actually don't see how to merge all what I've seen about this problem and what I have at the moment, so i would be very grateful if someone could point out if i'm missing something.